# ggplot2 set specific color individual category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with 2 categories, each having True or false click count on a time series (date click per day)

```
   time                groupClick clickedTrue count
   <dttm>              <chr>      <fct>       <int>
 1 2016-06-02 00:00:00 A 0        0              57
 2 2016-06-02 00:00:00 A 1        1               1
 3 2016-06-02 00:00:00 B 0        0              50
 4 2016-06-02 00:00:00 B 1        1               5
 5 2016-06-03 00:00:00 A 0        0              64
 6 2016-06-03 00:00:00 A 1        1               2
 7 2016-06-03 00:00:00 B 0        0              68
 8 2016-06-03 00:00:00 B 1        1               4
 9 2016-06-04 00:00:00 A 0        0              53
10 2016-06-04 00:00:00 A 1        1               2
```

I wanted to assign specific color to each category. For example:

- if category groupClick="A 0" to set color to RED// "#FF0000"
- if category groupClick="A 1" to set color to Green// "#00FF00"
- if category groupClick="B 0" to set color to Blue// "#0000FF"
- if category groupClick="B 1" to set color to Navi blue// "#00FFFF"?

How do you specify it for geom_point?

My code so far:

```
ggplot(ABTestDFSum, aes(x = time, y = count)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=groupClick, size=count)) 
  # What do we add here
```

Comment: Have a look at `?scale_color_manual `.

Comment: `scale_color_manual(values = c(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example using `scale_color_manual` as suggested in the comments to your post.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(~time, ~groupClick, ~clickedTrue, ~count,
"2016-06-02 00:00:00", "A 0",        0,              57,
"2016-06-02 00:00:00", "A 1",        1,               1,
"2016-06-02 00:00:00", "B 0",        0,              50,
"2016-06-02 00:00:00", "B 1",        1,               5,
"2016-06-03 00:00:00", "A 0",        0,              64,
"2016-06-03 00:00:00", "A 1",        1,               2,
"2016-06-03 00:00:00", "B 0",        0,              68,
"2016-06-03 00:00:00", "B 1",        1,               4,
"2016-06-04 00:00:00", "A 0",        0,              53,
"2016-06-04 00:00:00", "A 1",        1,               2) %>%
  mutate(time = as.Date(time),
         groupClick = as.factor(groupClick),
         clickedTrue = as.logical(clickedTrue))

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = count)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = groupClick, size=count)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#00FFFF"))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, A Big THANKYOU Gregory
Not sure how to  give credit from Stackoverflow website

Comment: @cyberstellus Glad it worked. Credit is given by accepting the answer. You just click the checkmark to the left of the answer.